# Create "modulo 360" x-axis in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot coordinates{(10, 20)(90, 80)(170, -50)(290, 12)(350, 20)(5, -40)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

These coordinates represent longitude/latitude point on the Earth, but the problem is that the two last points are "wrongly" connected by tikz: I get a line from `(350, 20)` to `(5, -40)` but I would like the line to go to the right axis (at 360) and come back from the left (at 0).

Basically, I would like to have a "modulo 360" x-axis. Is there a way to do this using tikz or do I have to split this plots into multiple ones?

Answer (score 3):

In order to get the periodic plot, just restrict the plot range to `[0,360]` by dialing `xmin=0` and `xmax=360` and add the respective points outside the plot range.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=360]
    \addplot coordinates{(-10, 20)(5, -40)(10, 20)(90, 80)(170, -50)(290, 12)(350, 20)(365, -40)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]